# QEMU-KVM Freezes on Guest Reboot - How do I fix this?

Tags: windows, virtualbox, virtual-machine, qemu, kvm

I haven't tested it on a Linux guest, but on a Windows 10 virtual machine guest most reboots freeze in the middle of starting back up. This has never happened with me on VirtualBox, and I wouldn't expect it to since that's usually stable and KVM is finicky as hell, as I've found out. Though it is indeed significantly faster than VirtualBox so I want to get this fixed.

I have to Force-Off the guest every time this happens.

I'm using EndeavourOS, LTS Kernel, KDE Plasma, X11, T470p Thinkpad (including discrete Nvidia GeForce 940MX [*Nvidia Optimus default set to use discrete alone*]), 32 GB DDR4 3200MHz, M.2-2280 NVMe 1TB.

Comment: I've not tried Windows 10 specifically on KVM, but Windows Server 2016 (which I think is the server equivalent of windows 10) works fine on KVM - did you install the virtio-win drivers in the guest?

Comment: By the way, you said VirtualBox is stable? I take it Oracle got their sh!t together in the last 5 or so years, because VirtualBox was anything BUT stable for me (years ago) - though I guess you said it's "usually stable" ... as opposed to KVM, which, through many upgrades in the last 5 years, has been rock solid stable